# Extract substrings that follow a pattern in Python with less code

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

My python string is with separated by \n newline at the end:

```
mystring = "owner: uid=rocdsc,ou=People,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com
member: uid=absylor12,ou=people,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com
member: uid=amslsmith,ou=people,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com
member: uid=amis,ou=people,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com
member: uid=null,ou=people,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com""
```

Is there a better way to generate an array of uid's only as follows:

```
[rocdsc, absylor12, amslsmith, amis]
```

without

> null

in the array list.

I tried:

```
uids= [name.strip() for name in mystring .split("\n")]        

    if len(uids)>0:
        for index in range(len(uids))
            #print 'Current UIDs:', uids[index].split(":")
            uids[0] = uids[0].split("=")[1].strip()
    print uids
```

Comment: Did you try a regular expression?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes I did @LorenzoPeña

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. You use the words shorthand and less iterations. What are you trying to optimize?

Comment: For the sake of correctness, please reword your question title and content so that you clarify you want to do it with less code, maybe?

Comment: I want to know the way to achieve same output using many libraries in python. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't tried regular expressions:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'uid=(\w+)')
r.findall(mystring)
```

If you want to remove the null you can `filter(lambda x: x != 'null', r.findall(mystring))` (one more iteration)

And this regular expression works, but will also remove all uids starting with the word null

```
re.compile(r'uid=((?!null)\w+)').findall(mystring)
```

Comment: is there a way to remove the null as uid, using the regex?

Comment: can't we do some exact match --> (^null|$)

Comment: The correct way is using this regex: r'uid=((?!null\b)\w+)'

Answer (score 1):

```
#!python2

import re

mystring = "owner: uid=rocdsc,ou=People,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com, member: uid=absylor12,ou=people,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com, member: uid=amslsmith,ou=people,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com, member: uid=amis,ou=people,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com, member:, uid=null,ou=people,dc=fcd,dc=test,dc=com"

# pattern definition
p = 'uid='

# holds user names
users = []

# split string on a space or a comma, find user id, append to list
for item in re.split(' |,|', mystring):
    if item.startswith(p):
        users.append(item.replace(p, ''))

print users
```